# Unable to install ionic in windows using npm

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm-install

I'm trying to install ionic using npm command

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

But installation failed. I'm have setup the proxy as well.

```
npm version:5.6.0
```

Proxy setup

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
npm config set proxy "http://username:password@proxyip:8080/"
npm config set https-proxy "http://username:password@proxyip:8080/"
```

Since I cannot post the complete error details from the log, I have extracted the error message alone.

> silly fetchPackageMetaData error for bn.js@^4.1.1 request to
>   http://registry.npmjs.org/bn.js failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED
>   proxyip:8080

Comment: You will need to set up your proxy properly. You should be able to get your proxy details from the browser: https://www.wikihow.com/Change-Proxy-Settings. If you don't use a proxy, you will need to remove the config option from NPM for it. (to be clear, "http://username:password@proxyip:8080/" is not a valid proxy address)

Comment: I have used the proper username,password and proxyip. But I have doubt on the proxyip. I cross checked the proxy settings in IE. Automatic script is used instead of specifying the proxy ip directly. Since I'm in the corporate network, I don;t have control on this. When I opened the script, it has two proxies. I have tried with both separately. But same issue exists.

Comment: With the same proxy setup, I tried to install grunt using the following command "npm install -g grunt-cli". It was successful. But for ionic only facing this error:(